# VSTO Development: opening a default browser from a Word ribbon with HTTP POST

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto, ribbon

SITUATION: I'm in the process of creating a Microsoft Word ribbon through a .NET VSTO project.  One button on the ribbon must collect some information from the opened document, and pass it through HTTP's POST method to a hosted Silverlight application that will take the input and do stuff with it.

Now, if I were using a **GET** method, the solution is simple:

```
Process.Start(string.Format("{0}?{1}", url, parameters));
```

...but I need to use **POST** due to the very large value length of my parameters.

Is it possible to open a default browser and perform an HTTP POST from a Microsoft Word ribbon (or any other .NET application)? If so, is there a code-sample I can follow?  If not, what are my alternatives?

Comment: You could embed the IE web browser control?

Comment: If you can't change the Web application to accept GET requests instead of POST you might have a look at WatiN or host your own simple proxy page that redirects a GET request to a POST request.